# permission change/disable how to?

Tags: android, android-manifest

How to disable this permission?
I'm using for Android Jellybean 4.2.2

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

---

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.laskardaeng.laskardaeng">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
    <permission android:name="com.laskardaeng.laskardaeng.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.laskardaeng.laskardaeng.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>
    <application android:debuggable="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="laskardaeng" android:largeHeap="true" android:name=".application.laskardaeng" android:theme="@style/Theme.laskardaeng">
```

Comment: Remove it? What are you asking exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Delete entire line.

When not explicitly enabled, permissions are disabled by default.

Quote from [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permissions):

> A basic Android application has no permissions associated with it by
>   default, meaning it cannot do anything that would adversely impact the
>   user experience or any data on the device. To make use of protected
>   features of the device, you must include in your AndroidManifest.xml
>   one or more  tags declaring the permissions that your
>   application needs.